# Attach element to arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, ecmascript-6, event-handling

I am using arrow functions to create an event on a button click, how do I attach an element to the function. Noob question.

```
  handleButtonClick(classId) {
    this.setState({
      classId
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        name="name"
        value={classId}
        onClick={e => this.handleButtonClick(e, classId)}
      >'Click me'
      </Button>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from changing

```
handleButtonClick(classId) {
```

to

```
handleButtonClick(e, classId) {
```

You can then access the element via the target property, i.e. `e.target`

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
handleButtonClick(classId) {
```

into

```
handleButtonClick(e, classId) {
```

since in onClick handler, you first passing e:

```
onClick={e => this.handleButtonClick(e, classId)}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add event argument in your function and you can access the input value by using event.target.value

```
    handleButtonClick(event,classId) {
     this.setState({
     classId:event.target.value
     });
    }
```